# PHP Header Location with parameter

Tags: php, http-headers

Is it possible to append a parameter to a PHP Header Location? I'm having trouble getting it to work. Is this syntax actually allowed?

```
$qry = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
header('Location: http://localhost/blast/v2/?$qry ') ;
```

it just won't replace $qry wit its actual value....why??

in the browser it ends up looking like this:

http://localhost/blast/v2/?$qry

thanks

Comment: This is fundamental stuff, have a read here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 23, accepted):

***Important note:* do not use this exactly if you cannot be sure that $qry is safe!**

Change the single quotes to double quotes:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/blast/v2/?$qry");
```

A single quoted string in PHP is treated as a *string literal*, which is not parsed for variables.

Double quoted strings *are* parsed for variables, so you will get whatever `$qry` contains appended, instead of literally `$qry`.

Comment: I try this one `header("Location:http://example.com/file.php?id=$ID");` but the header() adds a `/`at the end of `$ID` and making it a directory. That is it riderects to `http://example.com/file.php?id=5/`(Note the / at the end)

Please give a solution

Comment: Post a new question explaining your problem in detail. Don't hijack a post's comments

Comment: Great explanation @Bojangles.  For people reading this, you may also have heard the term "string interpolation," which is what's happening here.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add multiple parameters via a header like:

```
$divert=$row['id']."&param1=".($param1)."&param2=".($param2);
header("Location:showflagsab.php?id=$divert");
```

which adds the two additional paramaters to the original id

These can be extracted using the `$get` method at their destination

Comment: Mr.Howard.. I need your help in your ans code..your ans will send single record but incase if there are some duplicate records than how to store that in other page.?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old post, but please, do not do this. Parameters in a header are XSS vulnerable. You can read more about XSS'ing here: [owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Answer (score 0):

wiles How to Fix the XSS attack on header location

```
$param = $_REQUEST['bcd'];
header("Location: abc.php/?id=$param");
```