# Get the value of the textbox from 1 form to another form in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value from 1 form to another in php. In form1 there r fields such as name,email etc. After the  submitting the form it goes to another form where name,email value as to display from the form1. But in my form name,email doesnt display in form2. Here is the code.

form1.php

```
  <form method="post" name="XIForm" id="XIForm" action="registration.php">
        <p><label>Name</label><br/><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" style="margin-left:30px;" placeholder="Name"></p>
        <p><label>Email</label><br/><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" style="margin-left:30px;" placeholder="Email"></p>
```

```
<?php
    include_once 'db.php';
  if(isset($_POST['XISubmit'])) {

         $fname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $check_email="select * from reg where email='$email'";
        $run1=mysql_query($check_email);

        if(mysql_num_rows($run1)>0){
        echo "<script>alert('email already exits in our database. Please try with Another!')</script>";
        exit(0);
        }
     else{
              $query = "INSERT INTO reg(fname,username,password,cpassword,email) VALUES ('$fname','$username','$password', '$cpassword','$email')";
              $run11=mysql_query($query);
    $to=$_POST['email'];         
   if($run11){
    $_SESSION['sess_user4']=$username;
    echo "<script>alert('Registration Successful')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('attachfile.php', '_self')</script>";
    }
    }   
    }
    ?>
```

Form2.php

```
<form method="post" name="XIForm" action="attach.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();">
  <h4 style="color:#6f4617;margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family:Book Antiqua;color:#168eb6">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Welcome <?=$_SESSION['sess_user4']?>  </b>
<br/>

<label>Confirm Name</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" style="margin-left:30px;" placeholder="Name" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['fname'])) { echo $_GET['fname']; } ?>"  />
<br/><br/>
```

Comment: form2  is on save file..?

Comment: no.I need to get the value of name which is posted in form1 in form2. Form2 performs some other functions such as attaching the file and save it in db.

Comment: How do you forward to form2.php?

Comment: Can you give the URL of form2.php?

Comment: okk both form on same file then u can return value after submitting from or use jquery ajax for better

Comment: After registration suceesful it directly goes to form2 where user as to fill again name,email,attach file etc.after inserting these values it save in db

Comment: both form r on seperate file name

Comment: user header location

Comment: if i add <?php if(isset($_GET['fname'])) { echo $_GET['fname']; } ?>"  /> it doesnt get the value of name in form2.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this or more [PHP Header Location with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861925/php-header-location-with-parameter)

```
//after submitting form
header("Location: form2.php?fname=".$fname);
//then
 isset($_GET['fname']){
        echo $fname;

  }
```

Comment: In url i get fname whereas in form2.php fname doesnt appear

Comment: u mean u  r not getting value of fname on form 2 ..?

Answer (score 0):

You are using 
    echo $_GET['fname']; but you are sending a post through your form?